# The Visibility of MyContent breaks the ContentPresenter

Tags: c#, wpf

"The Visibility of MyContent breaks the ContentPresenter"

In the following code the ContentPresenter should render MyContent depending on the trigger. It seems to work when the initial visibility is changed to Hidden or when the ContentPresenter is replaced with a ContentControl.

What is wrong with using Visibility Collapsed on the ContentPresenter?

I have a `UserControl1` with 2 dependency properties:

```
public bool ShowMyContent
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(ShowMyContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(ShowMyContentProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty ShowMyContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ShowMyContent", typeof(bool), typeof(UserControl1));

public object MyContent
{
    get { return (object)GetValue(MyContentProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyContentProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyContentProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyContent", typeof(object), typeof(UserControl1));
```

and on my `MainWindow` a dependency property

```
public string MyProperty
{
    get { return (string)GetValue(MyPropertyProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MyPropertyProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MyPropertyProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("MyProperty", typeof(string), typeof(MainWindow), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("MyDefaultValue"));
```

Then the following XAML as my MainWindow:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:UserControl1}">
                    <!--  Try Visiblity="Hidden" or replace the ContentPresnter with ContentControl  -->
                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="Presenter"
                                      Content="{TemplateBinding MyContent}"
                                      Visibility="Collapsed" />
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="ShowMyContent" Value="True">
                            <Setter TargetName="Presenter" Property="Visibility" Value="Visible" />
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<StackPanel>
    <local:UserControl1 x:Name="userControl1">
        <local:UserControl1.MyContent>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}}" />
        </local:UserControl1.MyContent>
    </local:UserControl1>
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=ShowMyContent, ElementName=userControl1}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "breaks".  Also... why do you need to override your custom controls template? that seems a bit odd.  If all you want is the visibility of the content to change why not just bind the visibility to some property on your Windows ViewModel?

Comment: @chancea The RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=local:MainWindow}} cannot be resolved when the contentpresenters initial visibility is Collapsed. It (incorrectly) shows an empty textbox when the checkbox is checked.

Comment: I would not go down this road.  What you want is a ContentControl.  and just directly add the text box to the contentcontrol.  then use the built in Visibility of content control to bind to your MainWindow

Comment: @chancea Yes I understand but this is just a minimal reproduction of the issue I'm having. The problem seems to be that the RelativeSource in the TextBox is not resolved. When debugging the Binding the status shows PathError. I do not understand why this is a PathError, because when you just change the Visibilty from Collapsed to Hidden in the template it works. Why do I get a PathError is there any way to reset the binding when the textbox is visible? (Also When I use the Content property instead of MyContent, it also works for Collapsed so what am I missing?)